# Merge extra properties into second level JSON string

Tags: java, json, kotlin

I have a Json string like:

```
{
 "level 1": "hello",
 "level 2" : {
    "test1": 0,
    "test2": 5,
    "test3": "this is test"
  }
}
```

I want to merge 2 more fields into the `level 2` block (not root level). these are the following:

```
timeout = 5000
waityes = false
```

So the output JSON will be:

```
{
 "level 1": "hello",
 "level 2" : {
    "test1": 0,
    "test2": 5,
    "test3": "this is test",
    "timeout": 5000,
    "waityes": "false"
  }
}
```

I created a Kotlin data class with these 2 fields (not sure if this is the right thing to do??)

```
data class PropertiesToAdd(val timeout: Int = 5000, val waityes: String = "false")
```

But I am not sure how to merge the kotlin data class with the initial JSON string. Do I convert `PropertiesToAdd` to JSON first then somehow combine them??

I dont want to create model classes for the initial JSON object (the first example in this post).. (see again below)

```
{
 "level 1": "hello",
 "level 2" : {
    "test1": 0,
    "test2": 5,
    "test3": "this is test"
  }
}
```

I know I can use JSON object to merge two JSON but not sure how to add to a SECOND LEVEL element like `level 2` object in the example above.

Comment: Can you add some code for what you exactly need to add those two fields? Since you said you already need to create a model for your json and then add add the two fields, it is better to post your use case so it will be clear what you are trying to do and then it will be easy for anyone to suggest

Comment: I said I DONT want to create a model class for the input json. I just have the json string and want to combine it with the two new properties / kotlin data class with minimal code.

Comment: You have clearly written `have to create model classes for the initial json object` which is kinda contradictory to what you are saying here

Comment: So you're saying you have a JSON coming in from somewhere and then you need to add those two key-value pairs to it and then model it into a POJO?

Comment: no model classes .. just input json to output json string... i thought having a POJO for the 2 extra fields will help ?? but its not necessary. the important thig is getting the output json right @gtxtreme

Comment: Can't you just parse the string to a JSON Object, then add those two attribute "manually", without a data class?

Comment: https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon or any other library can help you with JSON parsing. However doing it rhrough the modelling into a data class is much easier. Take the string model it into a dataobject and then again deserialize it to a new json adding the two other fields

Comment: Not entirely familiar with the Kotlin/Java JSON API, but it should not be a problem to create a JSON Object, then access the "level 2" element as _another_ JSON Object and add to that.

Comment: Which library do you use? The question is labelled with Gson, but there is no code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work without the need for model classes:

```
val startJson = """
{
 "level 1": "hello",
 "level 2" : {
    "test1": 0,
    "test2": 5,
    "test3": "this is test"
  }
}"""

val endJson = JSONObject(startJson)
endJson.getJSONObject("level 2").put("timeout",5000).put("waityes","false")
```

`endJson.toString()` will be your desired output as follows:

```
{
 "level 1": "hello",
 "level 2" : {
    "test1": 0,
    "test2": 5,
    "test3": "this is test",
    "timeout": 5000,
    "waityes": "false"
  }
}
```